# jQuery submit function add data several times

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit, submit-button

I have this function I use to store items (voucher codes) based on some rules...

```
$("#serial_number").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
console.log('started');
        if (param == 'groupon' || param == 'livingsocial') {
            var secretS = $('#serial').val();
            var secretP = $('#pin').val();

            if ((/(?=[a-fA-F0-9]*[a-fA-F])[a-fA-F0-9]{10}/.test(secretS) === true) || (secretS.length == 13)) {


                var s = $('#serial').val();
                var p = $('#pin').val();
                var item = {}
                item["serial"] = s;
                item["pin"] = p;
                item["product_code"] = '74';
                item["promo_code"] = '74';
                item["covers"] = 2;

                jsonObj.push(item);
```

as you can see based on rexEg rule I write in IF condition I add an item to `jsonObj` so if it's valid I push into jsonObj an item.

If I type just once the correct serial based on rule like 123456789a everything is fine and I have this `[{serial: "123456789a", pin: undefined}]` which is fine...

**Problem is if:**

1. attempt - User type something like 1234 and try to submit a form but based o rules its item not stored into jsonObj
2. attempt - User type ggghhh55 also not stored into jsonObj
3. user finally submit correct serial like (123456789a) but then its added 3 times so I have this:

   [{serial: "123456789a", pin: undefined}, {serial: "123456789a", pin: undefined}, {serial: "123456789a", pin: undefined}]

Why? Why submit to form add item 3 times... should add it just once ...

Finally when the user enter correct serial then the form is submitted number of previous attempts ... so if there is 3 unsuccessful attempts form is submitted 3 times ...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to reset your jsonObj after each attempt